# Java source files are not getting compiled after making updation in source code on an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, jetty

I've tried a lot but fail to get latest compiled **.class** files for the source code after making some updation. The project is giving response same as in older source file. The updation on JSP files is getting reflect instantly but not in case of Java files.

J2EE project 
Eclipse Juno 
jetty-6.1.x

```
Jul 15, 2013 1:04:57 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader      readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Atul Dwivedi\git\careeryantra\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jul 15, 2013 1:04:58 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Atul Dwivedi\git\careeryantra\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Jul 15, 2013 1:04:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', valu'C:\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.1.1\appengine-java-sdk-  1.8.1.1\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from '    C:\Users\Atul Dwivedi\git\careeryantra\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Jul 15, 2013 1:04:58 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:59 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Jul 15, 2013 7:35:01 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
Jul 15, 2013 7:35:01 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: Server default is running at http://localhost:8888/
Jul 15, 2013 7:35:01 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Jul 15, 2013 1:05:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

Everything is fine with older java file but after making changes, It seems that project is running on the basis of older **.class** file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have checked "Build Automatically" checkbox in Project menu:
[image]

Comment: Yes, It was checked. I've tried to run it after doing unchecked. But exception is still there 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' for all **.class** files that are removed after cleaning the project.

Comment: Sometimes it is very hard to coax Eclipse to rebuild your project;-). Following are the steps you can try:  - restart Eclipse,  - clean and build project,  - modify classpath (change the output folder to and fro).  Sometimes I needed to do a few combinations of above steps, to make my project work properly. Sometimes also helps, to remove "Run configuration" and make Eclipse to create it automatically again or change classpath manually.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to project in the menu and select clean. Then select the project you wish clean to consider.

Comment: After cleaning the project. On running the project it throws <br />  java.lang.NullPointerException <br /> for each class files.

Comment: Right click your project and do a refresh. Hope this helps.